# Why do Python " ".split() and " ".split(" ") produce different result?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

This is the result when I apply split() against an empty string with default delimiter and with a " " as delimiter in Python.

```
>>> print(" ".split(" "))
['','']
>>> print(" ".split())
[]
```

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: In both Python 2 and Python 3 `"".split(" ")` returns a list of only _one_ empty string. Please double check your results.

Comment: what's unclear with the documentation?

Comment: Could not reproduce `print "".split(" ")`. Moreover, it looks like Python 2.x, why do you have Python-3.x tag?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation on `str.split`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) explicitly mentions the different behavior if you split with no argument and when you use `' '` as argument:

> #### `str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`
>
> [...]
>
> If *sep* is given, consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, `'1,,2'.split(',')` returns `['1', '', '2']`). The *sep* argument may consist of multiple characters (for example, `'1<>2<>3'.split('<>')` returns `['1', '2', '3']`). **Splitting an empty string with a specified separator returns `['']`**.
>
> [...]
>
> If *sep* is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. **Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.**

(Emphasis mine)