# What is difference of split(" ") and split()?

Tags: python

I'm sorry, I'm new to Python, so I'd be grateful if you could explain in detail.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645083/when-splitting-an-empty-string-in-python-why-does-split-return-an-empty-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do Python " ".split() and " ".split(" ") produce different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468317/why-do-python-split-and-split-produce-different-result)

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) explain this quite clearly:

> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.

That's the complex one; no `sep` (or `None` `sep`) means it splits on *runs* of any whitespace character, implicitly stripping any leading or trailing whitespace (rather than producing empty strings when it occurs). For any other argument, it just splits every time it sees the separator, so splitting on `' '` with an input of `'a  \tb'` (two spaces between `a` and `\tb` gets `['a', '', '\tb']`, where not passing `sep` would just produce `['a', 'b']` because the whole run of whitespace (including the tab) was treated as a single separator.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `split()` with parameters you are specifying a separator to be used. When you call it without params it uses any whitespace as separator.

Syntax:

```
string.split(separator, maxsplit)
```

- separator    Optional. Specifies the separator to use when splitting the
  string. By default any whitespace is a separator
- maxsplit Optional. Specifies how many splits to do. Default value is
  -1, which is "all occurrences"

When maxsplit is specified, the list will contain the specified number of elements plus one.

source: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Answer (score 1):

`string.split(separator, maxsplit)`

If you don't specify the seperator, whitespace(any whitespace including tabs etc) is used as default `separator` and consecutive whitespaces are grouped. If you specify whitespace yourself, consecutive whitespaces are not grouped.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.split

```
>>> s = 'a    b c'
>>> s.split()
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> s.split(' ')
['a', '', '', '', 'b', 'c']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to copy the documentation but I'd rather point out 2 major differences:

- without argument (or when passing `None` which is default), the separator is whitespace, *any* whitespace. Inclusing linefeed, vertical tabulation, carriage return, tab
- without argument, it splits according to the *maximum number of consecutive blanks*, guaranteeing that it doesn't produce empty strings in the split result.

Generally it's a bad idea to split with `' '` as an argument because it can lead to surprises. Better leave empty. If you want to maintain some empty strings on doubled separators, it means that you're reading a TSV file. In that case use the `csv` module with space as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

> > x='john,wick,wild,gnome'
> >
> > x.split()
> >
> > ['john,wick,wild,gnome']
> >
> > x.split(",")
> >
> > ['john', 'wick', 'wild', 'gnome']

in above examples you can see that a difference between split() & split("").
actually it works in this format ---> str.split(sep=None,maxsplit=-1)
It return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.
if sep is not specified then it takes default.